# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:{},{}

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried to fit a simple keras model using a train dataset with given details:
keras model:

```
def create_keras_model():
      initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=0)
      return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, kernel_initializer=initializer),
          tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
  ])
```

train_dataset:
<`list(tf_train_datasets[25].as_numpy_iterator())`

```
[OrderedDict([('x',
               array([[1023745],
                      [ 919922],
                      [1145516],
                      [1149189],
                      [     95]])),
              ('y',
               array([[0.],
                      [0.],
                      [0.],
                      [6.],
                      [0.]], dtype=float32))]),
 OrderedDict([('x',
               array([[1143669],
                      [ 272588],
                      [ 498358],
                      [ 890060],
                      [     99]])),
              ('y',
               array([[0.],
                      [5.],
                      [7.],
                      [0.],
                      [0.]], dtype=float32))]),
 OrderedDict([('x',
               array([[1115462],
                      [     98]])),
              ('y',
               array([[0.],
                      [0.]], dtype=float32))])]
```

when I try,
`keras_model.fit(tf_train_datasets, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)` I get a ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:
(<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.map_op._ParallelMapDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>

How should I modify the tf_train_dataset? I am confused.

I tried removing the preprocessing operation, but it gives another error. This is the create_tf_datasets function which inputs the ratings_df (has columns 'user-id','isbn','rating') and returns ordered dictionaries for each of the user-id.

```
def create_tf_datasets(ratings_df: pd.DataFrame,
                       batch_size: int = 1,
                       max_examples_per_user: Optional[int] = None,
                       max_clients: Optional[int] = None) -> List[tf.data.Dataset]:
  num_users = len(set(ratings_df['User-ID']))
  if max_clients is not None:
    num_users = min(num_users, max_clients)

  def rating_batch_map_fn(rating_batch):
      return collections.OrderedDict([
        ("x", tf.cast(rating_batch[:, 1:2], tf.int64)),
        ("y", tf.cast(rating_batch[:, 2:3], tf.float32))
    ])

  tf_datasets = []
  for user_id in range(num_users):
    # Get subset of ratings_df belonging to a particular user.
    user_ratings_df = ratings_df[ratings_df['User-ID'] == user_id]

    tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(user_ratings_df)

    # Define preprocessing operations.
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.take(max_examples_per_user).shuffle(
       buffer_size=max_examples_per_user, seed=42).batch(batch_size).map(
      rating_batch_map_fn,
       num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    tf_datasets.append(tf_dataset)

  return tf_datasets
```